# textarea white-space nowrap in combination with readonly

Tags: css

I have a simple textarea, where I only want to have manual line breaks.

Therefore I set the css property **white-space:nowrap** to the textarea.

When I give the textarea the attribute **readonly** and **disabled**, the manual line breaks disappear on Chrome 69.

Here is a working example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>.</title>
    <style>
    textarea
    {
        width:200px;
        height:100px;
        white-space:nowrap;
    }
    </style>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () =>
        {
            document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', (e) =>
            {
                if( !document.querySelector('textarea').hasAttribute('readonly') )
                {
                    document.querySelector('textarea').setAttribute('readonly','readonly');
                    document.querySelector('textarea').setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
                }
                else
                {
                    document.querySelector('textarea').removeAttribute('readonly','readonly');
                    document.querySelector('textarea').removeAttribute('disabled','disabled');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea>this
is
a
multilinemultilinemultilinemultilinemultiline
text</textarea>
    <br/>
    <button>toggle readonly</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Is this a bug I should report to the browser vendors or am I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: it seems white-space no wrap is working fine on the readonly state and not working on the normal state. because nowrap means no line break

Answer (score 3):

You can force the disabled state to also not wrap the text by using
`white-space: pre` instead of `white-space: nowrap`.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (!document.querySelector('textarea').hasAttribute('disabled')) {
      document.querySelector('textarea').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
      document.querySelector('textarea').removeAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<textarea>this
is
a
multilinemultilinemultilinemultilinemultiline
text</textarea>
<br/>
<button>Toggle 'disabled'</button>
```

The problem with using `white-space: nowrap` is that sequences of whitespace will collapse into a single whitespace. This check refreshes whenever the DOM is repainted, which happens when your button click adds the `disabled` attribute. `white-space: pre` fixes the problem by having the browser preserve the whitespace.

NB: `readonly` has no impact on display, so I've simplified my answer by removing this.

Comment: `The problem with using white-space: nowrap is that sequences of whitespace will collapse into a single whitespace.` --> it's not the case on his example; thus the bug